# Using flask flashes on heroku

Tags: python, heroku, flask

I have a very simple app, that asks questions and moves to the next question when a question is answered correctly and send me an sms message. When it is answered incorrectly, a flashed message appears and the page reloads. I'm trying to push this on heroku but the flashed messages seem to be causing the app to crash. When the flashed messages are commented out, the app works well. When they are not, I see a 500 Internal Server Error.

Question: How can I push flashed messages when this app is deployed on heroku?

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def main():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('landing.html')
    elif request.form['answer'].lower() == "coffee":
        message = "Step 1 completed"
        server.sendmail(from_address, to_number, message)
        return redirect(url_for('step_two'))
    else:
        message = "Sorry, that was the wrong answer. Please try again."
        flash(message)
        return render_template('landing.html')
```

The template that is rendering is extending the base and setup to show the flashed messages upon reloading.

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
    {% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %}
        {% if messages %}
            <ul class=flash style="list-style-type: none;">
                {% for message in messages %}
                    <li>{{ message }}</li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        {% endif %}
    {% endwith %}
```

Comment: Does it work when you run locally? What modules are you importing?

Comment: I am using these as imports:
`from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, request, render_template, flash
import smtplib
import os`

Comment: yes, it does work locally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a templating error which could explain why I wasn't seeing any logs. Apparently class=flash isn't just for styling in this case.
I had:

```
<ul class=flash style="list-style-type: none;">
```

and it should have been:

```
<ul class=flashes style="list-style-type: none;">
```

Answer (score 0):

From doc

> > The flashing system basically makes it possible to record a message at the end of a request and access it on the next (and only the next) request

So I think you have to redirect it.

```
flash(message)
return redirect(url_for('main'))
```

Comment: Man, I was hoping this would be a solution. Unfortunately though it doesn't work. Thanks for the idea though.

Answer (score 0):

Flask flash messages works with sessions.

It is just a long shot, but maybe you didn't defined the `SECRET_KEY` configuration, so your app is unable to set the messages to your session.

Comment: There is a secret key set. I wish it was that easy.